# function returning nan in for loop when performing multivariate linear regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am performing multivariate linear regression in pure python as seen from the code below.Can someone please tell me what's wrong in his code?
I have done the same for univariate linear regression. It performed well in it!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_df=pd.DataFrame([[2.0,70.0],[3.0,30.0],[4.0,80.0],[4.0,20.0],[3.0,50.0],[7.0,10.0],[5.0,50,0],[3.0,90.0],[2.0,20.0]])
y_df=pd.DataFrame([79.4,41.5,97.5,36.1,63.2,39.5,69.8,103.5,29.5])
x_df=x_df.drop(x_df.columns[2:], axis=1)

#print(x_df)

m=len(y_df)
#print(m)

x_df['intercept']=1
X=np.array(x_df)
#print(X)
#print(X.shape)
y=np.array(y_df).flatten()
#print(y.shape)
theta=np.array([0,0,0])
#print(theta)

def hypothesis(x,theta):
    return np.dot(x,theta)

#print(hypothesis(X,theta))

def cost(x,y,theta):
    m=y.shape[0]
    h=np.dot(x,theta)
    return np.sum(np.square(y-h))/(2.0*m)

#print(cost(X,y,theta))

def gradientDescent(x,y,theta,alpha=0.01,iter=1500):
    m=y.shape[0]

    for i in range(1500):
        h=hypothesis(x,theta)
        error=h-y
        update=np.dot(error,x)
        theta=np.subtract(theta,((alpha*update)/m))


    print('theta',theta)
    print('hyp',h)
    print('y',y)
    print('error',error)
    print('cost',cost(x,y,theta))

print(gradientDescent(X,y,theta))
```

and the output I get is :-

```
theta [ nan  nan  nan]
hyp [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
y [  79.4   41.5   97.5   36.1   63.2   39.5   69.8  103.5   29.5]
error [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
cost nan
```

Can someone please help me in solving this? i have been struck like almost 5 hours trying!

Answer (score 1):

Your learning rate is too large to converge, try alpha=0.00001.

Comment: thank you so much Yang! How is it you know that?the learning rate convergence thing! by just looking at code?

Comment: print(error=h-y), If it doesn't shrink in every iterations, try smaller learning rate. Learning rate means how fast you approach the optimal point. If alpha's too large, it'll run across the optimal point in every iterations. Suppose your distance between current point and the optimal point is 5 units. And the step you take to approach is alpha*update = 10 unit. It turns out that gradient descent won't converge to the optimal point because you run across it in every iterations.